# find command returning multiple rows in AIX

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I have a shell script which basically runs every day to create a list of files from previous day and count the number of requests inside the file.

For the purpose of creating list of files I use the `find` command as below

```
find ${Search_Path} -type f  -newer ./start-time \! -newer ./end-time |egrep '\.5500\.|\.5000\.' >IncomBQR.txt
```

In the past I faced a problem that it seems to be outputting multiple row

So I tried to fix it by creating a uniq list as below.

```
sort -u IncomBQR.txt>IncomBQR1.txt
cat IncomBQR1.txt>IncomBQR.txt
rm -f IncomBQR1.txt
```

But after a few month that also failed. Could you please help me debug the problem?

When It runs the command I get is

```
${Search_Path}/file1   
${Search_Path}/file1
```

where as I should be getting only one row for "file1"

However the strange thing is that when I manually run it finds only 1 row.

Comment: I think we need some examples of text. But since a unique sort does not weed out duplicates you may have empty spaces invisible to the eye, but easily detected by wc (word count) or similar.

Comment: @komenten  : Thanks for providing the response 
The file name are below :

`/gtpfssharepath/ORGXXXX/processed/billRequest/myrquest-20160312.DAT`

in my output listing it looks like this

`/gtpfssharepath/ORGXXXX/processed/billRequest/myrquest-20160312.DAT |35
/gtpfssharepath/ORGXXXX/processed/billRequest/myrquest-20160312.DAT |35`

I am wondering the problem might be due GPFS file system ?

Comment: Perhaps find also looks in the `IncomBQR.txt` and add grep-results of that file. Try redirecting the find output to a place in another directory tree like `/tmp/IncomBQR.txt`.

Comment: If manually running `find` only returns the file once (as it should) then there's a problem with your script. While post-processing the file might patch over the problem, it's not fixing it.

Comment: Does Search_Path contain multiple directory entries? Repeating a directory name will cause the duplicate output.  Try debugging echo "Searcn_Path=$Search_Path;";

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your `find` command and avoid the pipe to `grep`:

```
find "$Search_Path" -type f -newer ./start-time ! -newer ./end-time -name '*.5[50]00.*'
```

If you're seeing the same file returned multiple times, this is most likely a problem with your script, and not the result of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually use "uniq" in your fixup attempt, sorting is not enough. You can do it in one invocation:

```
find ... | sort | uniq > IncomBQR.txt
```